# ApiControllerActionSelector equivalent in Asp .net MVC core

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-mvc

we are migrating from web api to asp .net mvc core , i had an action selector in web api , in which if anyware in url "$" symbol exist we used to invoke a specific method in controller.
this functionality we achieved in web api using ApiControllerActionSelector below was the code to do same in web api -

```
public override HttpActionDescriptor SelectAction(HttpControllerContext controllerContext) {
           string urlDecode = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(
               controllerContext.Request.RequestUri.ToString());
           if (urlDecode != null && urlDecode.Contains("$")) {
               if (controllerContext.Request.Method == HttpMethod.Post) {
                   MethodInfo method = controllerContext.ControllerDescriptor.ControllerType
                       .GetMethod(
                           "PostCustomOperation");
                   return
                       new ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor(
                           controllerContext.ControllerDescriptor, method);
               }
               if (controllerContext.Request.Method == HttpMethod.Get) {
                   MethodInfo method = controllerContext.ControllerDescriptor.ControllerType
                       .GetMethod(
                           "GetCustomOperation");
                   return
                       new ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor(
                           controllerContext.ControllerDescriptor, method);
               }
           }
           HttpActionDescriptor result = base.SelectAction(controllerContext);
           return result;
       }
```

I am not able to find an equivalent way to do same in Asp .net mvc core , i tried implementing IRouter but in that we have to specify controller as well but that is not known to me.
Any suggestion on how to achieve same or is i not possible to do in Asp.net MVC core?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is `IActionSelector`. You can register an implementation for it in ConfigureServices, `services.AddSingleton<IActionSelector, CustomActionSelector>()`. The default implementation is `ActionSelector`, and you can delegate to it in your custom implementation.

Comment: Since [ActionSelector](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/a1ec03e1e65580b09a4dec5f2041a354bdca376d/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/Infrastructure/ActionSelector.cs) is marked as `internal`, can you suggest a strategy for how to delegate to it? If so, you have my vote. :)

Comment: No, it isn’t: https://zslearn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.internal.actionselector?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Comment: Then what did I link to on [GitHub](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/a1ec03e1e65580b09a4dec5f2041a354bdca376d/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/Infrastructure/ActionSelector.cs)? I see `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionSelector` is internal whereas the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ActionSelector` to which you linked is public. Oddly, that `Internal` namespace is not on GitHub. So it is like Github moved the source to `Infrastructure` and made it internal.

Answer (score 0):

I opted to replace `IActionInvokerFactory` instead. It was shorter. Here is the implementation. Then I create my own IActionInvoker wrapper.

My goal was to call the controller action again if necessary.

```
public class PolicyActionInvokerFactory : IActionInvokerFactory
{
    private readonly IEFConcurrencyService efConcurrencyService;
    private readonly IActionInvokerProvider[] actionInvokerProviders;

    public PolicyActionInvokerFactory(
        IEFConcurrencyService efConcurrencyService,
        IEnumerable<IActionInvokerProvider> actionInvokerProviders
    )
    {
        this.efConcurrencyService = efConcurrencyService;
        this.actionInvokerProviders = actionInvokerProviders.OrderBy(item => item.Order).ToArray();
    }

    public IActionInvoker CreateInvoker(ActionContext actionContext)
    {
        var context = new ActionInvokerProviderContext(actionContext);

        foreach (var provider in actionInvokerProviders)
        {
            provider.OnProvidersExecuting(context);
        }

        for (var i = actionInvokerProviders.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            actionInvokerProviders[i].OnProvidersExecuted(context);
        }

        return new RetryActionInvoker(efConcurrencyService, context.Result, actionContext);
    }

    class RetryActionInvoker : IActionInvoker
    {
        private readonly IEFConcurrencyService efConcurrencyService;
        private readonly IActionInvoker inner;
        private readonly ActionContext actionContext;

        public RetryActionInvoker(
            IEFConcurrencyService efConcurrencyService,
            IActionInvoker inner,
            ActionContext actionContext
        )
        {
            this.efConcurrencyService = efConcurrencyService;
            this.inner = inner;
            this.actionContext = actionContext;
        }

        public Task InvokeAsync()
        {
            var methodInfo = actionContext.ActionDescriptor;
            var shouldUseRetryLogic = methodInfo.EndpointMetadata.Any(m => m is RetryOnDbExceptionAttribute);
            if (shouldUseRetryLogic)
            {
                return efConcurrencyService.RetryOnError(() => {
                    // You will need to rewind the body here if you are using [FromBody]
                    // This is a little out of scope, but you should EnableBuffering()
                    // Then rewind the body with something like this:
                    // actionContext.HttpContext.Request.Body.Seek(0, System.IO.SeekOrigin.Begin);
                    return inner.InvokeAsync();
                });
            }

            return inner.InvokeAsync();
        }
    }
}
```